# Interpretation of Breslow Estimator for Baseline hazard

Tags: probability, statistics

I am trying to understand the intuition behind Breslow's estimator of baseline hazard for a survival model. The Estimator is defined as follows:

$$\lambda_{0}(t_j)=\frac{d_j}{\sum_{k\in \mathbb{R}(t_j)}\text{exp}(\beta^{T}Z_k)}$$

Note: $\mathbb{R}(t_j)$ is the collection of observations that are at risk at time $t_j$, $d_j$ are sample that have experienced event, T is a time to event random variable,  and $Z$ are covariates.
The derivation is based on this similarity:

$$d_j\approx\sum_{k\in \mathbb{R}(t_j)}P(t_j<T_k<t_j + \Delta t|T_k>t_j)$$

I am having trouble making sense of this connection. Can someone explain the intuition behind this.

Comment: Better to ask on the stats site.

Answer (score 1):

The significance of the hazard function $\lambda(t)$ for a survival model is that it is sufficient to describe the distribution of the lifetime through $P(T > t) =: S(t) = e^{-\int^t_0 \lambda(s) \,\mathrm{d} s}$. (For example, the hazard function can be defined by $\lambda(t) = -\frac{S'(t)}{S(t)}$.) In the proportional hazards model, we assume that the hazard function takes a semi-parametric form: $\lambda(t) = \lambda_0(t) \exp(\beta^T Z_k)$.

To come up with an estimator for the baseline hazard $\lambda_0(t)$, we approximate the number of events $d_j$ that happen at time $t_j$ with the expected number of events that happen based on our survival model, which depends on the pool of risks $\mathbb{R}(t_j)$ still active at $t_j$. That is, $d_j$ is approximately the number of events that happen in the interval $[t_j, t_j + \Delta t]$, and the occurrence of the event for risk $k$ is approximately Bernoulli($p_k$), where
$$
p_k = P(t_j < T_k < t_j + \Delta t \,|\, T_k > t_j) = \frac{S_k(t_j) - S_k(t_j + \Delta)}{S_k(t_j)}
$$
Since $\lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \frac{S_k(t_j) - S_k(t_j + \Delta)}{\Delta t \, S_k(t_j)} = \lambda_k(t)$, we can approximate $p_k \approx \Delta t \cdot \lambda_k(t_j)$. Further approximating with $\Delta t = 1$ and putting all this in together with the proportional hazards assumption, we have
$$
d_j \approx \sum_{k \in \mathbb{R}(t_j)} P(t_j < T_k < t_j + \Delta t \,|\, T_k > t_j) \approx \sum_{k \in \mathbb{R}(t_j)} \lambda_k(t) = \lambda_0(t) \sum_{k \in \mathbb{R}(t_j)} \exp(\beta^T Z_k).
$$
Rearranging gives the estimator $\lambda_0(t) = d_j / \sum_{k \in \mathbb{R}(t_j)} \exp(\beta^T Z_k)$. Thus, $\lambda_0(t)$ can be interpreted as describing the "instantaneous probability" that the event happens at a particular time (recall that a lot of classical probability is counting the ratio of favourable outcomes to all possible outcomes; with this estimator, we assume the baseline hazard is discrete at the times $t_j$ when the event has actually happened from the data).

As for the correctness of this, I think looking at an actual proof would be better, but hopefully this gives some intuition to accompany the rigour.